# Vungle SDK problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-errors, ads

I am trying to implement the Vungle Ad network to my app. I followed the documentation [here](https://v.vungle.com/dev/ios#title7). When I build and run, it fails with this:

```
  
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libvunglepub.a(UIViewController+VGAppStoreViewController.o)
  "_SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", referenced from:
      -[UIViewController(VGAppStoreViewController) prepareStoreViewController:] in libvunglepub.a(UIViewController+VGAppStoreViewController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: More specifically you need to link the StoreKit framework to your target.

Comment: Or you can add it via [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/?q=vungle).

Comment: Thank you all… It must have missed the StoreKit framework. It works now.